# How to add TextButton in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutterflow, flutter-text-button

[image]

This is the design I want to create here you can see the "Sign In" Text is a button. I want to create a TextButton in flutterFlow, but I can't see any widget in flutterFlow for a TextButton. There is only an option for the Button widget if you add the Button widget it also has a background Color. There is one option I know that I only added a button widget and made it transparent. What do you recommend for best practice?
Here is the result of what I made
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would add a **Row** with two children. a **Text** widget and another **Text** widget that is styled as you have shown.

Then add a onTap Action to the second **Text** widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Text widget.

Row(
Children[
Text("Already Have an account?"),

Text("Sign In") //add onTap action on this text and it will behave as a text button.

click on the Text widget, go to actions, click add action. and add your required action, it you case it may be. Navigate to Login Page.
]
)